# PHP/JSON - how to parser that stdClass Object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I have some JSON, and I've run it through some PHP that basically parses the JSON and decodes it as follows:

```
$request = array(
'object' => 'App',
'action' => 'getList',
'args' => array(
'sort' => 1,
'appsPerPage' => 15,
'page' => 1,
'deviceid' => 1));


$wrapper = array(
'request' => json_encode($request));

$wrapper = urlencode(json_encode($wrapper));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.apptrackr.org/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "request=$wrapper");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($response);
```

result:

```
    object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["code"]=> int(200) ["data"]=> string(14100) "{"apps": {"id":303917165,"add_date":1314083737,"last_modification":1314083737,"name":"my Fish 3D Aquarium","seller":"
```

and more few "apps" at the end ...

now, i try this:

```
    foreach ($response->apps as $app) {
    .......
    ......
    }
```

it's not working...need help.

thanks

Comment: What is happening? Are there any error messages?

Comment: var_dump($response) or print_r($response)?

Comment: i get this error:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: How do I get the "data" value to use on foreach and parser all "apps" arrays ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your backend method return something like

```
{code:200, data: '{"apps":{"id":303917165, ....}"};
```

Note that data is **json_encoded string**.

The simple way to workaround this is:

```
$response = json_decode($response);
$real_response = json_decode($response->data,true);
//$real_response is an array with 'apps' key containing your data
```

The right way is to fix backend to return just data, so the raw response is something like

```
{"apps":{"id":303917165,....}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$response->apps` is not an array. `$response->data` is a json format string. You can use `json_decode` to turn it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

IT looks like your object is something like:-

```
class Object {
    var code = 200;
    var data = "Big long JSON string here";
}
```

You should do something like

```
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach ($data->apps as $app)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: i get: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Here `json_decode($data)` return stdClass object that can't be use in foreach so it throws error. A good practice is to use `is_array($data)` before foreach. And for convert stdClass to array you can use `json_decode($data, true)`.